# VLC Bug - does not play more then once

Tags: video, vlc

After I updated to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the VLC stopped working: It Open the file and when I close it, the taskbar icon does not disappear, even when I uninstalled it - just disappeared when I reinitialised the system. And then (I tried every way to do this) It stopped to open any file, files that I am used to open, movie that I have already watched - so I am sure its not codec problem.
After that, I found an update, by the update manager, and download it (between them there was one for VLC) and I also downloaded the "Ubuntu restricted extras" to make sure it was not a codec problem.
Then I could watch the new episode of GOT, but after that, VLC opens just the audio of my downloaded videos.

Some one knows how to deal with it? I am a novice Ubuntu user and I love it! Until now, this is my biggest problem, and its a hell of a problem, cause I cant watch my movies!

Many Thanks,

Gabi Fleury.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. Would you care to share what error messages that it displays on the screen or may be its worth sharing screen shot of the error. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in a Terminal window:

```
vlc --reset-config --reset-plugins-cache
```

and this might be enough to get vlc working correctly...

Comment: Thanks!! It worked perfectly! I love you! You were the only one that made my vlc work! <3

Comment: Good to hear :)